# Replace openFileOutput to save Files in subdirectory

Tags: android

I have used many times `openFileOutput`.

Example:

```
FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = openFileOutput(fileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Now I noticed that all the files using `openFileOutput` method will be placed in the private app `files` directory.

It looks like:

> /data/data/com.my.app.app/files/example.txt

How can I replace this method to store the Files on subdirectory?

Example:

> /data/data/com.my.app.app/files/subdirectory/example.txt

Comment: There is nothing from stopping you creating directories in your private app space. You can use the standard File class. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3458008/creating-files-in-sub-directories-in-android

Answer (score 16, accepted):

> How can I replace this method to store the Files on subdirectory?

Replace:

```
FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = openFileOutput(fileName, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

with:

```
File dir=new File(getFilesDir(), dirName);

dir.mkdirs();

FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream(new File(dir, fileName));
```

where `dirName` is the name of your desired subdirectory.